# How could I decode the input data of a transaction?

Tags: java, decode, web3-java

I'm using web3j in java to get the input data of a transaction. I can get the data, but the problem is how can I decode this data.

Input data: "0x070ec83b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015118f200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.........."

```
String inputdata = null;

Optional<Transaction> tx = web3.ethGetTransactionByHash(txHash).send().getTransaction();

if (tx.isPresent()) {
    inputdata = tx.get().getInput();
}

//DECODE

byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(inputdata.substring(2).toCharArray());
System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
```

When you execute the code what you get is a variety of characters.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znWvT.png)

Comment: Perhaps the encoding is wrong. Try others, like US-ASCII. Namely, try this System.out.println(new String(bytes, "US-ASCII"))

Comment: I did it as your suggestion and I get this "È;`Qò à ` à ` 1juan12.456.123-9Inacap45.566.963-8
odontologo0xasdasetcdasdaetc120920198232358" :/

Comment: Have you ever found a way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not savvy with nodeJS but here's how to do it in python in case.

```
txn = web3.eth.get_transaction(txHash)                                  
txnInput = routerContract.decode_function_input(txn.input) 
print(txnInput)
```

Comment: web3js does not have that function